# Android Creative SnapKit: Photo with attachment Url pop-up opens twice

Tags: android, branch.io, snapkit

I am trying to share Image on **SnapChat** with attached URL generated from Branch IO. For that I have used **Creative SnapKit**.

When I clicked on the attached link, it gives me two pop-ups.

1. First pop-up redirects me to Playstore
2. The second pop-up redirects me to the installed app.

Ideally, if an app is installed then it should only give a single pop-up which redirects to the App.

I am using the following version:

```
implementation([ 'com.snapchat.kit.sdk:creative:1.6.3', 'com.snapchat.kit.sdk:core:1.6.3' ])
```

Implementation:

```
snapCreativeKitApi = SnapCreative.getApi(getActivity());
snapMediaFactory = SnapCreative.getMediaFactory(getActivity());

SnapPhotoFile photoFile;
try {
  photoFile = snapMediaFactory.getSnapPhotoFromFile(fileName);
} catch (SnapMediaSizeException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return;
}

SnapPhotoContent snapPhotoContent = new SnapPhotoContent(photoFile);
snapPhotoContent.setAttachmentUrl(urlToShare);
finish();
snapCreativeKitApi.send(snapPhotoContent);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.snapchat.kit.sdk.clientId" android:value="ClientID" />
```

We are using same keys for iOS and Android. For iOS, it's working as expected.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

Here is the video link for the issue I am facing:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivpshfs9o15kivr/20-08-20-10-32-07.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution & it was because of Branch IO configuration:
I have changed the configuration > DeepView Manager > Branch Default Bridge Template.

I put Canonical Identifier and Canonical URL as mentioned in the documentation.
For more information, read below Branch IO documents:

https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/deepviews

https://blog.branch.io/branch-concepts-the-branch-universal-object/